remove `nomachine` incomplete, start with no gui
I have installed nomachine (server and client) with gdebi and the bash files provided by NX. I tried to connect with ssh within a network based on zerotier nodes. Did not work well and I want to remove nomachine.
Using apt purge nomachine works and uses the NX provided routines. Only, linux (debian 12 bookworm) starts afterwards with a black screen and blinking cursor. From the log files I understand that lightdm greeter cannot start, searching for a file /usr/NX/scripts/vgl/vglenkey which was deleted by the purge but the call was left (where?)
How can this be fixed? The workaround is to reinstall nomachine and then stop the server and click do not start at next boot I would rather have it cleanly gone!
